# Are all SE sites accessible?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to suggest Stack Exchange network to a friend who is visually impaired. He lost his vision a couple of years ago to Glaucoma and is slowly finding his feet on the web using Screen Reader Software.

I just want to know if SE network sites are accessible using screen readers.

I tried to find the answer using search but I only managed to get results from StackOverflow and UserExperience SE and not any information if SE sites were themselves accessible or not. Nor did "Questions that may already have your answer" suggestion retrieve relevant results.

Please excuse me if this question is indeed a duplicate and it would be really nice if someone could point me to previous discussions on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shadow Wizard. I will take a look at the answers posted.

Comment: There appear to be things that can be improved. [one site's accessibility report](http://try.powermapper.com/Reports/7b98fe35-cd62-4a5a-9ce3-0cb364ac6745/report/map.ACC.htm).

Comment: Sure thing, good luck! And if you wonder, I doubt something has changed in those years since the original question and its answers have been posted. SE made some major design changes (e.g. profile page, changing CSS base library) but I don't think they changed something regarding accessibility.